# Can someone provide me with more information on forcing an https via .htaccess?

Tags: ajax, mod-rewrite, https

I want to force users to use HTTPS on a web page using my .htaccess file. Below is the code to add to my .htaccess file to do so. But before I actually implement this code, I would like some questions answered first. The line in particular that is confusing to me is line 4 so if anyone could explain line 4 in a little more detail I would be grateful! I see that it is using a regular expression but I don't know why. I understand the regular expression but what is it being used for?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a match-all expression to satisfy the syntax for the [`RewriteRule` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> Syntax:   RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]

and use it as part of the new URL.
This rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

will match anything from the start (`^`) of the request string to the end (`$`) and make it available as `$1` because of the grouping parentheses (`()`).

Note however, that it will redirect `http://www.yourdomain.com/foo` to `https://www.yourdomain.com/folder/foo` (it adds `folder/`).